# how to convert multiple array to single array this format

Tags: php

this is my array

```
Array( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => 907 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => 205 
        [1] => 251 
        [2] => 256 
        [3] => 334 
        [4] => 938 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [0] => 209 
        [1] => 213 
        [2] => 310 
        [3] => 323 
        [4] => 408 
        [5] => 415 
        [6] => 424 442 
        [7] => 510 
        [8] => 530 
        [9] => 559 
        [10] => 562 
        [11] => 619 
        [12] => 626 
        [13] => 628 
        [14] => 650 
        [15] => 657 
        [16] => 661 
        [17] => 669 
        [18] => 707 
        [19] => 714 
        [20] => 747 
        [21] => 760 
        [22] => 805 
        [23] => 818 
        [24] => 831 
        [25] => 858 
        [26] => 909 
        [27] => 916 
        [28] => 925 
        [29] => 949 
        [30] => 951 
    ) 
)
```

i have

```
array( 
    [0] => 907 
    [1] => 205 
    [2] => 251 
    [3] => 256 
    [4] => 334 
    [5] => 938 
    [6] => 209.. 
)
```

all multiple array in single array how

Comment: messy view. post in understandable format...

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. You should attempt to describe your issue better. Do you want to make it into a one-dimentional array, or something else? Show what you have already tried. We are not here to write code for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get all entries into a single array then the simplest solution for you could be to loop through the array using nested for loop